# Cracking The Coding Interview - Print all positive integer solutions to the equation

Tags: algorithm

In the book Cracking The Coding Interview

There is an example:

> Print all positive integer solutions to the equation
>
> `a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3`
>
> where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are integers between `1` and `1000`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/660XN.png)

In the book it states that "only one could work", but I don't get that.

As I can see, as long as all those variables are equal, it will work

Example:

```
a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1
a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 2
a = 3, b = 3, c = 3, d = 3
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are definitely multiple solutions. Are you sure that those are all the requirement from the book? Or the context of `only one could work` is really what you mean?

Comment: I think you're asking about a sentence in a book "only one could work", but without context, it's hard to do so. Obviously it doesn't mean there's only one solution (or it's very mistaken), since there are many solutions.

Comment: I found the book, and you've missed the context about breaking out of the `d` loop when you find a solution because only one value of `d` can work (for a given `a`, `b`, `c`).

Comment: What if we exclude *trivial solutions* i.e.  if we require `a != c, a !=d, b != c, b != d`?

Comment: regarding the d loop it seems unecessary to iterate up until a d value is found. A simple hashmap holding all the d^3 solution would be faster (checked against a^3 + b^3 - c^3)

Comment: There are even **8**  nontrivial **triplets**, e.g. `11**3 + 493**3 = 90**3 + 492**3 = 346**3 + 428**3`

Comment: When something doesn't seem to make sense about a text that you've just scanned, the first thing to do is go back and read all the words in order.

Comment: I get what it means now. When it has found the value d that works for a given a, b and c, then there is no reason to continue further in that innermost loop... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html)

Answer (score 2):

As a kind of guess (what is the question about?) let me show how to solve these kind of problems (in order to demonstrate it in the interview); you are quite right, there are a lot of *evident solutions*, like

```
  1**3 + 1**3 = 1**3 + 1**3
  1**3 + 2**3 = 2**3 + 1**3
```

All we have to do is to set `a = c` and `b = d` or `a = d` and `b = c`. What about *non-trivial* solutions like those below?

```
   1**3 +  12**3 =   9**3 +  10**3
  84**3 + 280**3 = 217**3 + 231**3
```

Please note, that we can *swap* `a` and `b` or / and `c` and `d`, and have a *derivative* solution like

```
  12**3 + 1**3 = 10**3 + 9**3
```

to exclude them let's assume `a <= b`, `c <= d` and `a < c`

Naive code with nested loops (which is mentioned in the book) lasts too long: we have `1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 = 1e12` operations to compute.
We can, however, use *meet in the middle* technique and have the result in a fraction of a second (with *two* inmost loops removed):

1. Compute all `a**3 + b**3` values (just `1000 * 1000 = 1e6` operations - upper bound)
2. Group them
3. Filter out interesting groups

**C# code:**

```
  Dictionary<long, List<(long, long)>> cubes = new Dictionary<long, List<(long, long)>>();

  for (long a = 1; a < 1000; ++a) {
    long a3 = a * a * a;

    for (long b = a; b < 1000; ++b) {
      long key = b * b * b + a3;

      if (cubes.TryGetValue(key, out var list))
        list.Add((a, b));
      else
        cubes.Add(key, new List<(long, long)>() { (a, b) });
    }
  }
```

Now we have `cubes` be like this

```
  {2, {(1, 1)}} // group with one (a, b) pair
  {9, {(1, 2)}} // another group with one (a, b) pair
   ...
  {1729, {(1, 12), (9, 10)}} // <- the group we are looking for!
   ...
```

Time to query the groups:

```
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cubes
  .Where(pair => pair.Value.Count >= 2)
  .Select(pair => $"{string.Join(" = ", pair.Value.Select(t => $"{t.Item1}**3 + {t.Item2}**3"))}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1**3 + 12**3 = 9**3 + 10**3
1**3 + 103**3 = 64**3 + 94**3
1**3 + 150**3 = 73**3 + 144**3
1**3 + 249**3 = 135**3 + 235**3
... 
22**3 + 986**3 = 180**3 + 984**3 = 692**3 + 856**3
...
802**3 + 987**3 = 883**3 + 924**3
```